# How to handle Java method calls from XSLT while debugging XSL files?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, xslt, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug an `XSLT` in `Eclipse` using `Xalan 2.7.1` processor. But whenever it comes to a point where there is a call made to any Java method, it terminates with the exception saying could not find perticular method.

I have searched this forum thoroughly but didn't find any question/answer which addresses this type of issue.

Is there any other way we can debug XSLT with java calls , can we use [intellj-xslt debugger](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1818?pr=) here ?

Comment: Any comments on this.